# Общий метод для работы с двумя классами в Java 8

Tags: java

У меня есть два полностью одинаковых класса `First` и `Second`. Также есть метод, который обрабатывает поля класса `First` и возвращает `ArrayList <First>`.

Как изменить метод, чтобы он также мог обрабатывать класс `Second` и возвращать `ArrayList <Second>`?

**Проблема** в том, что в методе, во время обработки, создаются объекты класса `First` (`new First`), а как, в зависимости от полученного типа, создать `Second` (`new Second`) в том же методе?

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Info> infoList1 = new ArrayList<>();
        List<Info> infoList2 = new ArrayList<>();

        Info info1 = new Info("Name1", "Type1");
        Info info2 = new Info("Name2", "Type2");

        infoList1.add(info1);
        infoList2.add(info2);

        List<First> firstList = getFirstList(infoList1);
        List<Second> secondList = getSecondList(infoList2);
    }

    public List<First> getFirstList(List<Info> infoList) {
        List<First> firstList = new ArrayList<>();
        infoList.forEach(info -> firstList.add(new First(info.getName, info.getType)));
        return firstList;
    }

    public List<Second> getSecondList(List<Info> infoList) {
        List<Second> secondList = new ArrayList<>();
        infoList.forEach(info -> secondList.add(new Second(info.getName, info.getType)));
        return secondList;
    }
}

public class First {
    private String name;
    private String type;

    public First(String name, String type) {
        this.name = name;
        this.type = type;
    }
}

public class Second {
    private String name;
    private String type;

    public Second(String name, String type) {
        this.name = name;
        this.type = type;
    }
}
```

Comment: Для этого есть Interface. Описываете его и реализуете. Например интерфейс ITest, а метод возвращает  ArrayList <ITest>.  Посмотреть можно здесь https://metanit.com/java/tutorial/3.7.php

Comment: @Виктор , а как заполнять ArrayList <ITest>, если в одном случае мне нужно создавать и класть объекты First, а в другом случае создавать и класть объекты Second?

Comment: Вы код добавьте к вопросу - предметно можно будет обсуждать

Comment: передавайте класс в качестве аргумента метода. В методе создавайте новый инстанс переданного класса

Comment: @Виктор, добавил код. Получается, что два метода полностью одинаковые, отличается только создаваемый объект и возвращаемое значение.

Comment: Ещё надо класс First

Comment: @Виктор, добавил First и Second

Comment: Тогда я вообще не понял зачем Вам класс Second? Используйте в обоих случаях класс First. List<First> secondList = getSecondList(infoList2);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для решения данной задачи достаточно написать обобщенный метод, который вместе со списком входных данных будет принимать функцию-конвертор типа `Info` в нужный класс, причём такая функция может передаваться в виде лямбды:

```java
public static <T> List<T> getList(List<Info> list, Function<Info, T> creator) {
    return list.stream().map(creator::apply).toList();
}

// SecondFactory
public static Second build(Info item) {
    return new Second(item.getName(), item.getType());
}


// вызов в методе main
List<First> first = getList(infoList1, it -> new First(it.getName(), it.getType()));
List<Second> second = getList(infoList2, SecondFactory::build);
```

Такое функциональное решение избавит от создания излишних общих "родительских" интерфейсов и/или классов для `First` и `Second`.

Однако, следует заметить, что полное дублирование кода в классах `First` и `Second` является признаком плохого кода.

Answer (score 2):

Как вариант реализации:

```
interface TwoClasses
{
    void TwoClasses(String name, String typeV);
}

class First implements TwoClasses
{
    private String name;
    private String typeV;
  
    First(String name, String type){
          
        this.name = name;
        this.typeV= type;
    }
}

class Second implements TwoClasses
{
    private String name;
    private String type;
  
    public Second(String name, String type){
        this.name = name;
        this.type= type;
    }
}

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Info> infoList1 = new ArrayList<>();
        List<Info> infoList2 = new ArrayList<>();

        Info info1 = new Info("Name1", "Type1");
        Info info2 = new Info("Name2", "Type2");

        infoList1.add(info1);
        infoList2.add(info2);

        List<TwoClasses> firstList = getList(infoList1, First.class);
        List<TwoClasses> secondList = getList(infoList2, Second.class);
    }

    public List<TwoClasses> getList(List<Info> infoList, Class cls) {
        List<TwoClasses> oList = new ArrayList<>();
        infoList.forEach(info -> firstList.add(
          cls.getDeclaredConstructor(String.class, String.class).newInstance(info.getName, info.getType)
          )
        );
        return oList;
    }
}
```